# How to use Django model inheritance with signals?

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I have a few model inheritance levels in Django:

```
class WorkAttachment(models.Model):
    """ Abstract class that holds all fields that are required in each attachment """
    work            = models.ForeignKey(Work)
    added           = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    views           = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class WorkAttachmentFileBased(WorkAttachment):
    """ Another base class, but for file based attachments """
    description     = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    size            = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('size in bytes'))

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class WorkAttachmentPicture(WorkAttachmentFileBased):
    """ Picture attached to work """
    image           = models.ImageField(upload_to='works/images', width_field='width', height_field='height')
    width           = models.IntegerField()
    height          = models.IntegerField()
```

There are many different models inherited from `WorkAttachmentFileBased` and `WorkAttachment`. I want to create a signal, which would update an `attachment_count` field for parent work, when attachment is created. It would be logical, to think that signal made for parent sender (`WorkAttachment`) would run for all inherited models too, but it does not. Here is my code:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=WorkAttachment, dispatch_uid="att_post_save")
def update_attachment_count_on_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """ Update file count for work when attachment was saved."""
    instance.work.attachment_count += 1
    instance.work.save()
```

Is there a way to make this signal work for all models inherited from `WorkAttachment`?

Python 2.7, Django 1.4 pre-alpha

P.S. I've tried [one of the solutions I found on the net](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/13fbbda47224888d), but it did not work for me.

Comment: I've found [the solution page in web archives](http://web.archive.org/web/20120715042306/http://codeblogging.net/blogs/1/14). There's one drawback of the solution - you should declare signal after all subclasses, otherwise it won't find them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
model_classes = [WorkAttachment, WorkAttachmentFileBased, WorkAttachmentPicture, ...]

def update_attachment_count_on_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.work.attachment_count += 1
    instance.work.save()

for model_class in model_classes:
    post_save.connect(update_attachment_count_on_save, 
                      sender=model_class, 
                      dispatch_uid="att_post_save_"+model_class.__name__)
```

(Disclaimer: I have not tested the above)

Comment: Just FYI, you can find blog post by @SilverLight at: https://web.archive.org/web/20120715042306/http://codeblogging.net/blogs/1/14

Answer (score 55):

You could register the connection handler without `sender` specified. And filter the needed models inside it.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    # Returns false if 'sender' is NOT a subclass of AbstractModel
    if not issubclass(sender, AbstractModel):
       return
    ...
```

Ref: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/E_u9pHIkiI0/YgzA1p8XaSMJ

Comment: This works but has a slight drawback in that the receiver function gets called for every model that calls `save()`.

Answer (score 30):

The simplest solution is to not restrict on the `sender`, but to check in the signal handler whether the respective instance is a subclass:

```
@receiver(post_save)
def update_attachment_count_on_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(instance, WorkAttachment):
        ...
```

However, this may incur a significant performance overhead as *every* time *any* model is saved, the above function is called.

I think I've found the most Django-way of doing this: Recent versions of Django suggest to connect signal handlers in a file called `signals.py`. Here's the necessary wiring code:

**your_app/__init__.py:**

```
default_app_config = 'your_app.apps.YourAppConfig'
```

**your_app/apps.py:**

```
import django.apps

class YourAppConfig(django.apps.AppConfig):
    name = 'your_app'
    def ready(self):
        import your_app.signals
```

**your_app/signals.py:**

```
def get_subclasses(cls):
    result = [cls]
    classes_to_inspect = [cls]
    while classes_to_inspect:
        class_to_inspect = classes_to_inspect.pop()
        for subclass in class_to_inspect.__subclasses__():
            if subclass not in result:
                result.append(subclass)
                classes_to_inspect.append(subclass)
    return result

def update_attachment_count_on_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.work.attachment_count += 1
    instance.work.save()

for subclass in get_subclasses(WorkAttachment):
    post_save.connect(update_attachment_count_on_save, subclass)
```

I *think* this works for all subclasses, because they will all be loaded by the time `YourAppConfig.ready` is called (and thus `signals` is imported).

Comment: good answer. Note that ```result``` in ```get_subclassed``` contains the parent class, which matches this question. If your parent class is an abstract Model, you would want ```result``` to be an empty list initially.

Answer (score 18):

I just did this using python's (relatively) new [`__init_subclass__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation):

```
from django.db import models

def perform_on_save(*args, **kw):
    print("Doing something important after saving.")

class ParentClass(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        models.signals.post_save.connect(perform_on_save, sender=cls)

class MySubclass(ParentClass):
    pass  # signal automatically gets connected.
```

This requires django 2.1 and python 3.6 or better. Note that the `@classmethod` line seems to be required when working with the django model and associated metaclass even though it's not required according to the official python docs.

Comment: It's `__init_subclass__`.

Comment: very nice solution

Comment: This is a great solution! I configured this to work to connect to the m2m_changed signal instead. I'll add my answer below.

Comment: This is perfect as it avoid triggering on save() multiple times

Answer (score 8):

```
post_save.connect(my_handler, ParentClass)
# connect all subclasses of base content item too
for subclass in ParentClass.__subclasses__():
    post_save.connect(my_handler, subclass)
```

have a nice day!

Comment: You need to make sure this is run after all possible subclasses have been defined or else they'll get skipped (though, I haven't tested that assertion, I think that's what would happen).

Answer (score 6):

Michael Herrmann's solution is definitively the most Django-way of doing this.
And yes it works for all subclasses as they are loaded at the ready() call.

I would like to contribute with the documentation references :

> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals submodule of the application they relate to. Signal receivers are connected in the ready() method of your application configuration class. If you’re using the receiver() decorator, simply import the signals submodule inside ready().

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions

And add a warning :

> The ready() method may be executed more than once during testing, so you may want to guard your signals from duplication, especially if you’re planning to send them within tests.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions

So you might want to prevent duplicate signals with a dispatch_uid parameter on the connect function.

```
post_save.connect(my_callback, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
```

In this context I'll do :

```
for subclass in get_subclasses(WorkAttachment):
    post_save.connect(update_attachment_count_on_save, subclass, dispatch_uid=subclass.__name__)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals

Answer (score 2):

This solution resolves the problem when not all modules imported into memory.

```
def inherited_receiver(signal, sender, **kwargs):
    """
    Decorator connect receivers and all receiver's subclasses to signals.

        @inherited_receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
        def signal_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
            ...

    """
    parent_cls = sender

    def wrapper(func):
        def childs_receiver(sender, **kw):
            """
            the receiver detect that func will execute for child 
            (and same parent) classes only.
            """
            child_cls = sender
            if issubclass(child_cls, parent_cls):
                func(sender=child_cls, **kw)

        signal.connect(childs_receiver, **kwargs)
        return childs_receiver
    return wrapper
```

Comment: this is built on the http://stackoverflow.com/a/17173716/433570 and without the defects which SilverLight mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use content types to discover subclasses - assuming you have the base class and subclasses packaged in the same app. Something like this would work:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
content_types = ContentType.objects.filter(app_label="your_app")
for content_type in content_types:
    model = content_type.model_class()
    post_save.connect(update_attachment_count_on_save, sender=model)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @clwainwright answer, I configured his answer to instead work for the m2m_changed signal. I had to post it as an answer for the code formatting to make sense:

```
@classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for m2m_field in cls._meta.many_to_many:
            if hasattr(cls, m2m_field.attname) and hasattr(getattr(cls, m2m_field.attname), 'through'):
                models.signals.m2m_changed.connect(m2m_changed_receiver, weak=False, sender=getattr(cls, m2m_field.attname).through)
```

It does a couple of checks to ensure it doesn't break if anything changes in future Django versions.